# c++ access violation with classes

Tags: c++

Hi I am getting an access violation reading error in my linked list header file. The project takes a binary tree and turns it into an ordered linked list. the binary tree header:

```
 #ifndef BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H
#define BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H

#include "dsexceptions.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;       

template <typename Comparable>
class BinarySearchTree
{
  public:
    BinarySearchTree( ) :root( NULL )
    {  }

    BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree & rhs) : root(NULL)
    { *this = rhs; }

    ~BinarySearchTree( )
    { makeEmpty( ); }

    const Comparable & findMin( ) const
    {
        if (isEmpty( ))
            throw UnderflowException( );
        return findMin(root)->element;
    }

    const Comparable & findMax( ) const
    {
        if(isEmpty( ))
            throw UnderflowException( );
        return findMax( root )->element;
    }

    bool contains(const Comparable & x) const
    { return contains(x, root); }

    bool isEmpty( ) const
    { return root == NULL; }

    void printTree(ostream & out = cout)
    {
        if (isEmpty( ))
            out << "Empty tree" << endl;
        else
            printTree(root, out);
    }

    void makeEmpty( )
    { makeEmpty(root); }

    void insert(const Comparable & x)
    { insert(x, root); }

    void remove(const Comparable & x)
    { remove(x, root); }

    const BinarySearchTree & operator=(const BinarySearchTree & rhs)
    {
        if (this != &rhs)
        {
            makeEmpty( );
            root = clone(rhs.root);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void toList(linkedlist l)
    { toList(l, root); }

  private:
    struct BinaryNode
    {
        Comparable element;
        BinaryNode *left;
        BinaryNode *right;

        BinaryNode(const Comparable & theElement, BinaryNode *lt, BinaryNode *rt)
            : element(theElement), left(lt), right(rt) { }
    };

    BinaryNode *root;
    void toList(linkedlist l, BinaryNode *&t)
    { 
        if(t==NULL)
        { return; }
        toList(l,t->left);
        l.add(t->element);
        toList(l,t->right);
    }

    void printTree(BinaryNode *&t, ostream & out = cout)
    {
        if(t==NULL)
        { return; }
        printTree(t->left,out);
        cout << t->element << endl;
        printTree(t->right,out);
    }

    void insert(const Comparable & x, BinaryNode * & t)
    {
        if (t == NULL)
            t = new BinaryNode(x, NULL, NULL);
        else if (x < t->element)
            insert(x, t->left);
        else if (t->element < x)
            insert(x, t->right);
        else;  // Duplicate; do nothing
    }

    void remove(const Comparable & x, BinaryNode * & t)
    {
        if (t == NULL)
            return;   // Item not found; do nothing
        if (x < t->element)
            remove(x, t->left);
        else if (t->element < x)
            remove(x, t->right);
        else if (t->left != NULL && t->right != NULL) // Two children
        {
            t->element = findMin(t->right)->element;
            remove(t->element, t->right);
        }
        else
        {
            BinaryNode *oldNode = t;
            t = (t->left != NULL) ? t->left : t->right;
            delete oldNode;
        }
    }

    BinaryNode * findMin(BinaryNode *t) const
    {
        if (t == NULL)
            return NULL;
        if (t->left == NULL)
            return t;
        return findMin(t->left);
    }

    BinaryNode * findMax(BinaryNode *t) const
    {
        if (t != NULL)
            while (t->right != NULL)
                t = t->right;
        return t;
    }

    bool contains(const Comparable & x, BinaryNode *t) const
    {
        if (t == NULL)
            return false;
        else if (x < t->element)
            return contains(x, t->left);
        else if (t->element < x)
            return contains(x, t->right);
        else
            return true;    // Match
    }

    void makeEmpty(BinaryNode * & t)
    {
        if (t != NULL)
        {
            makeEmpty(t->left);
            makeEmpty(t->right);
            delete t;
        }
        t = NULL;
    }

    BinaryNode * clone(BinaryNode *t) const
    {
        if (t == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else
            return new BinaryNode(t->element, clone(t->left), clone(t->right));
    }
};

#endif
```

the linked list header:

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class linkedlist
{
private:

struct lNode{ 
    int data;
    lNode *next;
};

struct lNode *head;

public:

    linkedlist()
    { struct lNode *head = new lNode;
      head->next = NULL; 
    }

void add(int n) {
    lNode *newlNode = new lNode; 
    newlNode->data = n;          
    newlNode->next = NULL;       

    lNode *cur = head;           
    while(true) {
        if(cur->next == NULL)
        {
            cur->next = newlNode;
            break;
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

void display() { 
    lNode *list = head;              

    while(true)
    {
        if (list->next == NULL)
        {
            cout << list->data << endl;
            break;
        }
        cout << list->data << endl;
        list = list->next;
    }
    cout << "done" << endl;
}

};

#endif
```

the main cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BinarySearchTree.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"
using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    BinarySearchTree<int> t;
    linkedlist l;
    int i;

    cout << "inserting nodes into tree" << endl;
    t.insert(50);
    t.insert(60);
    t.insert(30);
    t.insert(20);
    t.insert(40);
    t.insert(70);
    t.insert(55);
    t.insert(65);
    t.insert(25);
    t.insert(35);
    t.insert(85);
    t.insert(100);
    t.insert(15);
    t.insert(45);
    t.insert(95);
    t.insert(105);
    t.insert(10);
    t.insert(75);
    t.insert(110);
    t.insert(12);
    t.insert(92);
    t.insert(32);
    t.insert(82);
    t.insert(22);
    t.insert(32);

    t.printTree( );
    t.toList(l);

    cout << "Finished processing" << endl;
    l.display();

    return 0;
}
```

The location of the error is in the linked list header file here: if(cur->next == NULL). I do not see how it could be an access error as everything is contained inside that class.

Comment: It means an error accessing memory; it's nothing to do with `public`/`private`. Use a debugger and find out which of your pointers is dangling. While debugging, construct a [testcase](http://http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/). When you need help, post that testcase here.

Comment: Any reason you're rolling your own binary search tree instead of using `std::set`?

Answer (score 2):

In the code above you have this section of code:

```
struct lNode *head;

public:

    linkedlist()
    { struct lNode *head = new lNode;
      head->next = NULL; 
    }
```

That code is defining two instances of the *head* node which I'm sure is not what you want.

The ctor should be something more like this:

```
    linkedlist()
    { 
      head = new lNode;
      head->next = NULL; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not test for the empty list -- that is where there are no elements in the list and the head is NULL.

Also, you are missing any constructors which is initializing the class, so it may very well be that `head` has an undefined value -- also there `add` method make not use of the loop, or make any recording of the added elements...

So in short, there are a lot of programming issues to fix.

Comment: No theres a constructor for the linkedlist class :  

    linkedlist()
     { struct lNode *head = new lNode;
       head->next = NULL; 
     }
that creates the head node and sets its next pointer to NULL. It tests to check if the list is empty right here: 

 if(cur->next == NULL)
 {
  cur->next = newlNode;
  break;
 }
since cur = head if head doesnt point to anything then its would be NULL. So, i just set the  cur->next equal to the new node.

Comment: `cur` is set to `head`, so in the case of an empty list where `head` is NULL, you will have `cur->next` dreferincing a null pointer, as `cur` will be NULL

Comment: Your constrctor `linkedlist()` may be setting `head->next`, but what is `head` initialized to?   -- as far as I can see it is never initialized, so the setting of `head->next` would cause a problem...